# Output a count vector for each text, in a collection of texts using sklearn

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

Hi I have a collection of texts,
There are hundreds in the reals collection but i have a simplified example

```
words_dict ={ 'text1':"rabbit dog cat elephant cat horse", 'text2':"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 'test3':'horses are bad people'}
all_texts = []
for text, words in words_dict.items():
    all_texts.append(words)
    
    
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(all_texts)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
array = X.toarray()
```

this produces an array that looks like this

```
[[0 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 2]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

I want to convert this back to a dictionary, that contains the vocab index, and vocab word count for

```
wordcountDict = {'text1':['3:2','4:1','5:1','7:1', '14:1'], 'text2':['2:1','4:1','6:1','9:1','10:1''11:1''13:1''15:2'],'text3':['0:1', '1:1','8:1', '12:1']}
```

I know how to do this with nested for loop iterating over each item one by one, however  I am sure there has got to be a better way. Does anyone know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict(enumerate(row))` to create dictionary from each row of the `array` then filter the keys in dictionary whose values not equal to zero.

```
res = {y: [f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in dict(enumerate(x)).items() if v != 0] for x, y in zip(array, words_dict)}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'text1': ['3:2', '4:1', '5:1', '7:1', '14:1'], 'text2': ['2:1', '4:1', '6:1', '9:1', '10:1', '11:1', '13:1', '15:2'], 'test3': ['0:1', '1:1', '8:1', '12:1']}
```